# Sliced Variables in PARFOR loop: Sequential to Parallel Conversion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, parallel-processing, sequential, parfor

I have a code in MATLAB in which I'm running monte-carlo simulations using *parfor* instead of simple *for* loop to convert the code from sequential to parallel. Following is the piece of code which is inside the *parfor* loop.

But MATLAB gives an error saying "Valid indices for local_Q_mega_sub_seed are restricted in *parfor* loop". Suggested action says to "Fix the index" and it suggests to use "Sliced Variables". I've been struggling to use this concept. I have read https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/#12 and https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/123922-sliced-variables-in-parfor-loop-restricted-indexing along with MATLAB documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html but I'm not getting it right.

Could anyone please let me know how can I use sliced variables in the given piece of code so that I could get an idea?

```
index_f = 1;
subseed_step = (sub_seed_transmitted_at/fs_local)*sintablen_mega_frequency;
for i = 1 : fs_local
local_Q_mega_sub_seed(i) = SINTAB(round(index_f));
local_I_mega_sub_seed(i) = COSTAB(round(index_f));
index_f = index_f + subseed_step;
if index_f>sintablen_mega_frequency
    index_f = index_f - sintablen_mega_frequency;
end
```

Comment: Please add the complete piece of code (especially the `parfor` loop) as its hard to understand what happens to all the variables mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing enough context here, but I bet the problem here is similar to this one:

```
parfor ii = 1:10
    for jj = 1:10
        tmp(jj) = rand
    end
    out(ii) = sum(tmp);
end
```

In this case, the `parfor` machinery cannot categorically prove that the way `tmp` is being used is independent of the order of iterations of the `parfor` loop. This is because it *appears* as though values assigned to `tmp` in one iteration of the `parfor` loop are still being used in the next iteration.

Fortunately, there's a very simple workaround for this case - convince `parfor` that you are not doing anything dependent on the order of evaluation of the iterations of the loop by resetting the variable. In the simple case above, this means:

```
parfor ii = 1:10
    % reset 'tmp' at the start of each parfor loop iteration
    tmp = [];
    for jj = 1:10
        tmp(jj) = rand
    end
    out(ii) = sum(tmp);
end
```